# Infinite Dimensional Vector Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

For finite dimensional vector spaces $V,W$, we have $V \cong W$ if and only if $\dim(V)=\dim(W)$. I was wondering if a similar statement is true for infinite dimensional vector spaces, i.e.:

If $U$ is a vector space with basis $B$, define $\dim(U)= |B|$. Then does the above statement hold when $V,W$ are infinite dimensional ($\dim(V)$ is an infinite cardinal number)?

Comment: Depends what you want isomorphism to mean in this context. If two spaces are isomorphic if and only if there is *some* bijective linear map between them, then yes: your statement is correct.

Comment: However, we normally take infinite dimensional spaces to have some additional structure such as a topology or a norm. In that context, we might only consider spaces to be isomorphic if there is a *continuous* bijective and linear map between the spaces (with a continuous inverse).

Comment: Interesting. So if the term is meant to mean "isomorphic as vector spaces," then the claim holds, but if it is meant to mean "homeomorphic" it need not hold.

Comment: Exactly! ...as long as you assume the axiom of choice.  Dealing with arbitrary vector spaces without the axiom of choice is tough because we don't necessarily have a basis.  In fact, if we don't assume the axiom of choice, then there are vector spaces that, strictly speaking, have "no dimension".

Comment: It is also particularly notable that in finite dimensions, every norm produces exactly the same topology, and every linear map is continuous, so there is no distinction between "vector-space isomorphism" and "homeomorphism".